# azure-ad-b2c custom policy how to localize Error messages

Tags: azure, localization, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Hello iam looking for solution to localize error message to below message but seems it is not overriding

**1. Added localization to below content definition tried MergeBehavior="Prepend",MergeBehavior="Append" and MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll"**

```
  <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/unified.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:1.2.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.en" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
```

**2.Overriding localization using resources api.signuporsignin.en**

```
   <Localization Enabled="true">
          <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
            <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
          </SupportedLanguages>
          <LocalizedResources Id="api.signuporsignin.en">
            <LocalizedStrings>
         
              <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfInvalidPassword">We didn't recognize this username and password combination.</LocalizedString>
    
            </LocalizedStrings>
          </LocalizedResources>
        </Localization>
```

Can anyone suggest me any way to localize error messages in azure b2c custom policy(signupsignin)

Comment: Have you tried by calling `ui_locales` in the [query string parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#how-language-customization-works)..?

Comment: Tried using ui_locales in query parameter. No change I still not see the localised error message i have provided.